# What is the expected behavior of CBCentralManager after it has received a an event of type .resetting

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral, cbcentralmanager

In the app that I am working on we have a mechanism in place to handle CBCentralManager's state change when

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager)
```

fires and the incoming state is CBManagerState.poweredOff. We will keep track of the existing known peripherals and connect to them once CBManagerState.poweredOn comes through.

When it comes to CBManagerState.resetting though, I don't know what the expectations are in terms of wether I should be reconnecting to the peripheral.

The API documentation says:

`The connection with the system service was momentarily lost, update imminent.`

Does that mean that I am supposed to issue a connect to the peripheral once the update (presumably CBManagerState.poweredOn) comes through? Has anybody been able to reproduce CBManagerState.resetting?